# How to generate a random gaussian matrix with different variance along each axis

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I want to generate a N by M random gaussian matrix. I want the variance of this matrix to be low along the first axis, and high for the other. I have tried with multivariate_normal and `cov = [[sigma1, 0], [0, sigma2]]`, but what I get is 2 different N by M matrices, the first one with variance sigma1 and the second with variance sigma2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First generate an array of variance one, then row by row add numbers sampled from a distribution with higher variance.

```
M = 20
N = 20

a = np.random.normal(0, 1, (N, M))
b = np.random.normal(0, 3, N)[:, None]

print np.var(a + b, axis=0)
print np.var(a + b, axis=1)
```

Adding the same number to a row does not change its variance : var(X + k) = var(X), so the variance of rows are unchanged.
but considering a column, since the variance of the sum of independents gaussians is the sum of their variances, you have increased the variance.

Here the first variance is 1 (unchanged), and the second one is (approximately) 1^2 + 3^2 (the inputs for a and b are standard devs, not variances).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I didn't explain myself properly. Following from your example, what I meant is that `np.var(test[0, :])=np.var(test[1, :])=...=np.var(test[5, :])=1` and that `np.var(test[:, 0])=np.var(test[:, 1])=...=np.var(test[:, 3])=10`. I think that's not the case in your code

Comment: the variance of the resulting matrix (a+b) along axis=0 is the power of two of the variance of b, right?

Comment: No, it is just the sum of the original variance (0) and the variance of b (5)

Comment: that doesn't match what I observe if I plug some bigger numbers:

`M = 400
N = 1000
cov = np.diag(np.ones(M))
mean = np.zeros(M)
a = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, N)
b = np.random.normal(0, 10, N)[:, None]
In[13]: np.mean(np.var(a+b, axis=0))
Out[13]: 96.145156028149827
In[14]: np.mean(np.var(a+b, axis=1))
Out[14]: 0.9977979271523072`

Comment: @Anthony Sorry, see my edit. The second variance is the sum of the variances, or equivalently the sum of squared stddevs (1 and 3 in my example)